# .NET Core inside Docker image on Raspberry 4b

Tags: docker, .net-core, raspberry-pi, arm, containers

I have a Raspberry PI 4b with Raspbian installed.
Also installed Docker and it seems to work fine (tested it with `docker run hello-world`).

However I am trying to get the [.NET Core samples](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-samples) container running from microsoft.

`uname m` returns arm71 so that means it is `linux arm32` architecture.

When I run `docker run -it --rm mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:dotnetapp-buster-slim-arm32v7` I keep getting '**standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"**'.

To my understanding that basically means my container is targeting the wrong architecture. So I tried all other architectures but still no results.

My goal is to run a simple .NET Core 3.0 API inside a docker container on a Raspberry. This should be a first simple step but it is giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the steps above are correct. It's just the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples` image from microsoft that is corrupt / not working. 
Others like the runtime are working just fine.